# ubuntu 16.04 on MacBook Air does not boot

Tags: boot, uefi, macbook

I have tried to install ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot with OSX on my MacBook Air following these intructions (up to the installation of refind):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Trusty

The LiveCD works fine, the installation goes on without complaint. After rebooting, I have the choice between OSX (boots without problem) and an "EFI boot" option, that sends me to grub in command line mode, and I don't know how to boot to ubuntu from there. I suppose it's just some config file error, but I don't know how to fix this. Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to boot Ubuntu directly from rEFInd without involving GRUB. If you don't see such an option, then chances are one of two things is true:

- Your rEFInd installation lacks the EFI driver needed to read your Linux kernel. Re-installing rEFInd *might* fix this problem, but if you followed the procedure described in the page to which you linked *exactly,* rEFInd was installed after Ubuntu, and so the right driver *should* already be installed. You could double-check this by using the `mountesp` script that comes with rEFInd and looking for the appropriate driver. See the [rEFInd documentation on drivers](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/drivers.html) for more on this topic.
- Your Ubuntu installation went badly wrong in a way that's caused the kernel to not be installed, or perhaps to be installed in some inappropriate location. This possibility could also explain why GRUB isn't working correctly. Unfortunately, I can't be more specific, since there are *many* ways an Ubuntu installation can go badly wrong, and the symptoms you've described don't pinpoint the problem.

If you can't coax rEFInd into showing you an option to boot Ubuntu directly, you might want to run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which will help us better understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you! I think the first option was true: I noticed that the version of rEFInd I had installed was not the most recent one, so I reinstalled to the latest version and it now boots correctly.